# Selected option in HTML Select element gets added to options

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu, html-select

I populate the options of select element from types variable. Lets say option1 and option2. I get option1 from selectedType variable. Problem is when I click on dropdown I see three options to select {opion1, option2, option1}. Selected option is added to already populated options. Please suggest me where I am going wrong ?

```
<select name="types">
<c:forEach items="${types}" var="type">
<option>${type}</option>
</c:forEach>
<option selected="selected">${selectedType}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding duplicated options, it is necessary to compare inside the `forEach` if it is the selected one and then mark it as `selected`

Something like this:

```
<select name="types">
<c:forEach items="${types}" var="type">
    <c:when test="${type == selectedType}">
        <option selected="selected">${selectedType}</option>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <option>${type}</option>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```